# Data binding with XML linq

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have spent literally hours searching for how to do this and unfortunatly being a C# novice cannot work out how to do this although im sure its pretty simple. I am trying to grab the data I have stored in XML and bind it to a list. I was currently using the foreach method and just adding items to the listbox using the code but this seems inefficient and a bit clumsey when you want to store as much as I do. I'm using the following code to retreive items from IO at current:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                foreach (string items in storage.GetFileNames("*.item"))
                {
                        XElement _xml;

                        IsolatedStorageFileStream location = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(items, System.IO.FileMode.Open, storage);

                        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(location);
                        _xml = XElement.Parse(file.ReadToEnd());
                        XAttribute att = _xml.Attribute("att");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a sample project demonstrating xml -> linq -> data binding here.

[binding a Linq datasource to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72)

Comment: thanks, its working fine. One more question though, how would I get it to filter the data based on a descendent element. Using your person example, say i wanted all the people whose ages were equal to 29?

Thanks!

Comment: try something along the lines of: where ((int)query.Element("age")) == 29